# How can I get the result of MongoDB's collection.aggregate() in NodeJS callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following `users` collection:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b29ba37cd0b1726068731c3"),
    "name" : "Gym Dog",
    "profilePicUrl" : "https://i.imgur.com/mPStaKV.png",
    "totalProgress" : {
    "goal" : 300,
    "progress" : 0,
    "percentage" : 0
    },
    "goals" : [
    {
        "description" : "Running",
        "goal" : 100,
        "progress" : 0,
        "percentage" : 0
    },
    {
        "description" : "Lifting",
        "goal" : 200,
        "progress" : 0,
        "percentage" : 0
    }
    ],
    "days" : [
    {
        "weekday" : "Sunday",
        "content" : ""
    },
    {
        "weekday" : "Monday",
        "content" : ""
    },
    {
        "weekday" : "Tuesday",
        "content" : ""
    },
    {
        "weekday" : "Wednesday",
        "content" : ""
    },
    {
        "weekday" : "Thursday",
        "content" : ""
    },
    {
        "weekday" : "Friday",
        "content" : ""
    },
    {
        "weekday" : "Saturday",
        "content" : ""
    }
    ],
    "activities" : [ ]
}
```

**I would like to select the 2nd element of `goals` of the user `Gym Dog` and then return the result in a NodeJS callback function.**

---

Below is what I did in the **Mongo shell**:

```js
db.users.aggregate(
    { $match: { name: 'Gym Dog' }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        ithGoal: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$goals', 1 ] }
    }}
).pretty()
```

Result from Mongo shell. **This is also what I had expected my NodeJS code to output**

```js
{
    "ithGoal" : {
        "description" : "Lifting",
        "goal" : 200,
        "progress" : 0,
        "percentage" : 0
    }
}
```

---

Below is what I did in **NodeJs**:

```js
mongoDB.collection('users').aggregate(
// pipeline
[
    { $match: { name: 'Gym Dog' }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        ithGoal: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$goals', 1 ] }
    }}
],
// callback
function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

However, when `result` was logged into the console, it was an `AggregationCursor {}` object with a bunch of irrelevant info. It wasn't anything similar to the output from the Mongo shell (I don't include the output here because it's too long).

I tried `mongoDB.collection('users').aggregate().toArray(function(err, result) {});` too, but it output the entire JSON object with `name`, `profilePicUrl`, `totalProgress`, `goals`, `days`, `activitise` (in other words, it selected nothing from the conditions I gave).

So, my question is, **how can I get the callback function in NodeJS to store the exact same result as the Mongo shell's into the `result` parameter?**

I'm using MongoDB Community 3.6.5. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the [mongodb documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate), aggregate returns a cursor. So try `result.next(function(err, res) {console.log(res)})` to fetch the data. Though I am not sure whether this will give only the data you need. It might return the data you got from toArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax seems to correct. Please check the MongoDB connection URL.
But I am not sure, I am supposing that some database connection related issues

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and I solved it by verifying that the _id passed in the query, is a valid ObjectId, you can verify it as shown below.

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
ObjectId.isValid(your_data_id) // Returns either true or false.
```